# IP log all images in a directory

Tags: php, image, logging, ip

Say I have a directory with several images inside, I want to log all IP's in one big file that includes IP, date, time, and filename (the image). How would I do this? Heres a bit of code I already use to log IP's on specific pages, so if you could modify this, and I can keep that format, I would appreciate it.

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
$file = "visitors.log";
$logfile = fopen($file, "a");
$line = $ip . " | " . date("m.d.Y | H:i:s");
fwrite($logfile, $line . "\n");
fclose($logfile);
?>
```

NOTE: I have to use HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP instead of REMOTE_ADDR because I'm on Cloudflare.

Comment: Vague question. Log what IP's? Uploaders? Viewers? Where is this code loaded? Any framework? + 100 other questions

Comment: The PHP code provided is just simple code that I run on certain webpages (like the homepage of my site) that logs all the visitors in a .log file in this format: 127.0.0.1 | 11.03.2015 | 17:53:58. I also have a directory full of images (screenshots) and I would like to modify the code I currently have to somehow log visitor information from every single image, but all in one .log file. Like this: (127.0.0.1 | 11.03.2015 | 17:53:58 | filename.png)

Comment: Then you need to redirect all image request to a PHP file which logs the call and then serves the requested image. That will need some .htacccess hack (if you're using Apache) or some vhost-hacks if your on nginx... It's a bit much to ask us to give you all that code, though

Comment: I am indeed using Apache and am familiar with htaccess, the images are located in the root directory of one of my vhosts.

Comment: Then use htaccess to redirect all calls to images to a file called something like: image.php where you log the request in the same way that you have done earlier and then echo the content of the requested file. With the correct content type.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly to put in my htaccess?

Comment: And keep in mind that I would also like the filename logged.

Answer (score 2):

htaccess to catch all requests to images:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ image.php?image=$1.$2 [R,L]
```

This assumes that your image.php is in the root folder.

To get the requested file in your image.php-file:

```
$image = isset($_GET['image'])? $_GET['image'] : null;
```

Now you can add logging with the requested filename and return the real file to the visitor.

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this without affecting the url? I want it to be domain.com/image.png not domain.com/image.php?image=image.png

Comment: it's a non-transparent rewrite, not a redirect. The user only sees `domain.com/whatever.png`. The actuall request is handled by the server, not the browser.

Comment: Can you show me how to incorporate the $image = isset($_GET['image'])? $_GET['image'] : null;
 into the PHP code I provided earlier?

Comment: After the $image = isset(... add your log script and change the $line-line: `$line = $ip . " | " . date("m.d.Y | H:i:s") . " | " . $image;`

Comment: Ok, I have http://pastebin.com/9vCxjPr8 as my image.php, the logger is working and displaying the filename as it should when I go to the url of the image, the only issue is that the browser changes /img.png to /image.php?image=img.png and the page is white.

Comment: Actually, this rewrite isn't non-transparent.. it will redirect the user. My bad! How ever, it's just a matter of chaning the htaccess. Google is your friend. There are 10000 guides for this. Now it's 02:33 here and I'm drunk and have to work tomorrow so ... good luck! :)

Comment: Can you link me to a guide for this? I can't find any.

Comment: Google for: htaccess rewrite without redirect - If you can't manage that, there's nothing I can do to help you.